# Adding item to shopping cart PHP HTML only

Tags: php, html, shopping-cart

I have trouble when creating code for adding an item to shopping cart. What I did is echo each individual item customers could buy, and I wanted to add an input type for how many of that specific item they want, then "add to cart" button and repeat (echo another item, another input and button etc.)

```
while ($zaznam = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vysledek)) {
$soubor=$zaznam["img_nazev"];
echo "<div id='zbozi_info'>";
echo "<img src='img/$soubor'>";
echo "<p class='popis'>".$zaznam["dlouhy_popis"]."</p>";
echo "<p class='cena'> Cena bez DPH: ";
echo "<span style=color:#FF0000>".$zaznam["cena"]." Kč </span> </p>";
echo "<p class='cena'> Cena s DPH: ";
echo "<span style=color:#FF0000>".$zaznam["CenaDPH"]." Kč </span> </p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<form method='post'>
<label for='pocetk'>Počet kusů</label> 
<br>
<input type='text' name='pocetk' id='pocetk' value='1'>
<br>
<input type='submit' name='pridkos' id='pridkos' value='Přidat do košíku'>
</form>";
}
```

This works and all, the trouble starts when I add this if to the mix, to enable that adding function

```
if (isset($_POST["pridkos"]) && isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

$ksk="INSERT INTO kosik 
             (ID_uzivatele,ID_zbozi, pocet_kusu) 
      VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user']."',
              '".$zaznam["ID_zbozi"]."',
              '".$_POST["pocetk"]."');";


  $vysledek = mysqli_query($con,$ksk)  
         or die("Zboží nebylo přidáno do košíku");
```

This just dies on the mysqli_query. I am not exactly sure if to put it inside the while or outside, my suspicion is inside, but it isn't working either way
Session[user] has the user ID (ID_uzivatele), not sure what else can I clarify. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/1935077)

Comment: Yeah that is possible, thank you for this but that's not really my concern right now. I will not be using this commercialy in any way, it's for local host usage only. Still, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    I think this query syntax is wrong.

    Check with below one:-

    $ksk="INSERT INTO kosik(ID_uzivatele,ID_zbozi, pocet_kusu) 
          VALUES ('$_SESSION[user]',
                  '$zaznam[ID_zbozi]',
                  '.$_POST["pocetk"]')";
```